# MongoDB match all mongodb dates

Tags: mongodb

I would like to query a table that matches all of the given dates

My table structure is below with 3 sample records
I want to find all records that match dates in an array
['2016-03-31','2016-04-01','2016-04-02']

I have tried using $in but it is matching any one of the dates, I require 3 rows to be returned when all of the dates are available

In the records below there is no date for March 31st so no records should be returned

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56fa9606f1568a4e098b45ba"),
  "quantity": 11,
  "adate": ISODate("2016-04-01T00:00:00Z"),
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56fa9606f1568a4e098b45ba"),
  "quantity": 11,
  "adate": ISODate("2016-04-02T00:00:00Z"),
}, 
{
  "_id": ObjectId("56fa9606f1568a4e098b45ba"),
  "quantity": 11,
  "adate": ISODate("2016-04-03T00:00:00Z"),
}
```

Comment: have you tried giving timestamp format?
try converting it into milliseconds and search..

Comment: `db.collection.find({ "adate": { "$in": ['2016-03-31','2016-04-01','2016-04-02'].map(function(el) { return new Date(el) }) } })` So use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) for the list, but of course you need to "cast" to a `Date` in order to match. Typically speaking, real "dates" are rarely stored as the `0` hour time and you should be matching on a "range" instead. For which you can use `$or` with `$gte` and `$lt` for start of day and start of the next day.

Comment: I did a $in, but it is searching for any one of the dates, I require it to match all of the dates, ie ['2016-03-31','2016-04-01','2016-04-02']

Comment: I executed this query  db.inventory.find({available_date:{$in:[ISODate('2016-03-30'), ISODate('2016-03-31'), ISODate('2016-03-28')] } })


I have the following dates in the database  '2016-03-31' and '2016-03-30' i have not stored any record for date '2016-03-28'

My expected result is the query should not return any results, but it is returning for 30, & 31 because it matches any of the available dates